# Error message when using broom to get coefficients from glmmTMB zero inflation models

Tags: r, coefficients, broom

Using the Owls data and the `glmmTMB` package, I want to visually compare the regression coefficients from different zero-Inflated models that differ in the family used (ZIPOISS, ZINB1, ZINB2) and with/out the offset (logBroodSize).

However my first problem is to get the coefficients. The `tidy` function from package `broom` should provide you with the coefficients to plot them later with `ggplot`, but I get the following error when I try to get them:

```
modList= list(zipoiss, zinb1, zinb2, zinb1_bs, zinb2_bs)  
coefs= ldply(modList,tidy,effect="fixed",conf.int=TRUE,
                  .id="model") %>%
    mutate(term=abbfun(term)) %>%
    select(model,term,estimate,conf.low,conf.high) %>%
    filter(!term %in% c("Intercept","Intercept.1","NCalls","zi_NCalls"))

Error in as.data.frame.default(x) :
cannot coerce class ""glmmTMB"" to a data.frame
Also: Warning message:
In tidy.default(X[[i]], ...) :
No method for tidying an S3 object of class glmmTMB , using as.data.frame
```

Any idea of what could be wrong? I was already told that not having a right version of `broom` could be the reason, however I have had installed the right version of it... Code for a reproducible example is provided next:

```
    # Packages and dataset
    library(glmmTMB)
    library(broom) # devtools::install_github("bbolker/broom")
    library(plyr)
    library(dplyr)
    data(Owls,package="glmmTMB")
    Owls = plyr::rename(Owls, c(SiblingNegotiation="NCalls"))
    Owls = transform(Owls,
             ArrivalTime=scale(ArrivalTime, center=TRUE, scale=FALSE),
             obs=factor(seq(nrow(Owls))))

    # Models
    zipoiss<-glmmTMB(NCalls~(FoodTreatment+ArrivalTime)*SexParent+
    offset(logBroodSize)+(1|Nest),
    data=Owls,
    ziformula = ~ 1,
    family="poisson")

    zinb2<- glmmTMB(NCalls~(FoodTreatment+ArrivalTime)*SexParent+
    offset(logBroodSize)+(1|Nest),
    data=Owls,
    ziformula = ~ 1,
    family="nbinom2")

    zinb1 <- glmmTMB(NCalls~(FoodTreatment+ArrivalTime)*SexParent+
    offset(logBroodSize)+(1|Nest),
    data=Owls,
    ziformula = ~ 1,
    family="nbinom1")

    zinb1_bs<- glmmTMB(NCalls~(FoodTreatment+ArrivalTime)*SexParent+ 
    BroodSize+(1|Nest),
    data=Owls,
    ziformula = ~ 1,
    family="nbinom1")

    zinb2_bs<- glmmTMB(NCalls~(FoodTreatment+ArrivalTime)*SexParent+
    BroodSize+(1|Nest),
    data=Owls,
    ziformula = ~ 1,family="nbinom2")

    # Get coefficients ("coefs" does not work yet...)
    modList = list(zipoiss, zinb1, zinb2, zinb1_bs, zinb2_bs)
    coefs = ldply(modList,tidy,effect="fixed",conf.int=TRUE,
          .id="model") %>%
    mutate(term=abbfun(term)) %>%
    select(model,term,estimate,conf.low,conf.high) %>%
    filter(!term %in% c("Intercept","Intercept.1","NCalls","zi_NCalls"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now works (as of today) with the new/under-development [broom.mixed](https://github.com/bbolker/broom.mixed) package, e.g.

```
devtools::install_github("bbolker/broom.mixed")
```

Hopefully this will be on CRAN sometime soon, but it's only medium priority 
for me, and I don't want to release it to CRAN until it's at least 90% baked. Pull requests welcome!

The last step changed a little bit (for one thing, I don't seem to have `abbfun`):

```
modList = lme4:::namedList(zipoiss, zinb1, zinb2, zinb1_bs, zinb2_bs)
coefs = ldply(modList,tidy,effect="fixed",conf.int=TRUE,
              .id="model") %>%
  select(model,term,component,estimate,conf.low,conf.high) %>%
  filter(!term %in% c("(Intercept)","NCalls"))
```

**Caveat**: The development of these tools for `glmmTMB` models is pretty new/experimental; you should (1) sanity-check your results carefully and (2) [report an issue](https://github.com/bbolker/broom.mixed/issues) if something doesn't work as expected.